# Inserting into simple Postgres views

Tags: sql, postgresql

The [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS) says

> Simple views are automatically updatable: the system will allow INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to be used on the view in the same way as on a regular table.

It then lists a number of requirements. I believe that my view meets all these requirements, yet if I try and insert into that view, I get the error:

```
psql:C355A12.txt:1702: ERROR:  cannot insert into a view
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule.
```

The view I'm inserting into is defined as:

```
CREATE VIEW locationsView
    AS SELECT lc_name, lc_min, lc_max, lc_sizeX, lc_sizeY
    FROM locations;
```

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE locations(
    lc_name LocationName NOT NULL,
    lc_min LocationMin NOT NULL
        DEFAULT 0,
    lc_max LocationMax NOT NULL
        DEFAULT 0,
    lc_sizeX LocationSizeX NOT NULL,
    lc_sizeY LocationSizeY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (lc_name)
);
```

Domains used are:

```
CREATE DOMAIN LocationName AS TEXT;
CREATE DOMAIN LocationMin AS INT;
CREATE DOMAIN LocationMax AS INT;
CREATE DOMAIN LocationSizeX As INT;
CREATE DOMAIN LocationSizeY As INT;
```

How do I obtain this "automatically updatable"ness described by the documentation?

I'm using Postgres version 9.3.4.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the table `locations`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, definition of `locations` is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c354f5d62f7ea6585f30

Comment: Sorry, that's a problem with me renaming fields in the question to remove noise from the question. I've edited the question with an example of an *exact* code that reproduces the problem. I didn't mention the domains initially because I don't believe they're related to the problem (I can insert fine into the table, just not the view). I renamed the attributes because their naming scheme is required for the class that this is for.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 9.3? Because this *does* work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0a2c/1 What does `select version()` show you?

Comment: That's weird, the output of `select version()` is `PostgreSQL 8.4.20`, but the output of `psql --version` is `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4`. I guess that's the cause of the problem, then.

Comment: Probably the server I'm doing the assignment on is using an older version than our lab machines. I guess this question should be closed?

Comment: `psql --version` gives you the version of the psql client application, not of the Postgres server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading documentation for a newer version of the PostgreSQL server than what you're connecting to running (8.4).

Simply updatable view support was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.3. Your `psql` client is version 9.3, but that doesn't affect server-side features if connecting to an 8.4 server.